# Hi How can I am pretty new to guidewire, how can I configure a multiple options select dropdown in Guidewire 9.0?

Tags: configuration, guidewire, ng-multiselect-dropdown, claimcenter

I am trying to configure a multiple options select drop down in guidewire claim center 9.0

I am able to configure a drop-down and able select single options and drop down items are taken from a typelist

Comment: hey buddy use checkbox instead TypeKey Input

Answer (score 5):

You can configure a dropdown to enable multiple selections.  Use a RangeInput widget and set the multiSelect property to "true".  The value property must point to an array similar to what @SteveDrippsCentricConsulting described.

Full documentation of PCF components and their properties is available in the pcf.html document that is located at XXXCenter/modules in any InsuranceSuite developers deployment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a typelist, then below steps will ensure you can choose a value from a list of values

1. Ensure your pcf element is a TypeKey Input
2. In the value, you can map the column to which this will get mapped (Example `vehicleIncident.VehicleLossParty`)
3. In the value type, give the typelist that you are referring to (Example typekey.LossPartyType)
4. Verify your typekey has the relevant values.

There are other things like typefilters, range inputs and so on, but this should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly, I think you are asking how a drop down widget can be modified to allow multiple selections from the drop down list to be selected. Here's a breakdown of the things you would need to consider for this. Also, I do not think this would work with a simple TypeKey Input widget. This involves modifying the data model as well to allow this. Let's use an example where you are trying to add a work shift preference to the User entity.

You might start with a new typelist called `ShiftPreferenceType` that has 3 values `{"1st Shift", "2nd Shift", "3rd Shift"}`. This is obviously a simplified definition of a typelist. Assume that a user must select at least one preferred shift but can also select 2 or 3 preferred shifts if they have scheduling flexibility.

Then you would need to create an entity to join this typelist to the User entity. The join table `RolePrivilege` is the most appropriate comparison here. The `RolePrivelege` table allows Roles to be associated to multiple privileges in the `SystemPermissionType` typelist. Similarly you could create a join table for the user shift scenario with a join table named `UserShiftPreference` which has a foreign key to the `User` entity and a typekey column for the `ShiftPreferenceType` typelist. An array key would need to be added to the `User` entity to connect it to the `UserShiftPreference` join table.

Then after all that you would then be able to add a widget to a PCF to allow multiple shift preferences to be selected. Unfortunately, a simple dropdown is not possible to use in this case. The TypeKey Input widget cannot be used. Instead I would look at the RoleDetailDV pcf file and mimic that functionality to associate multiple typekey values to one entity. In this case a ListView with iterator buttons are used.

I hope this helps and let me know if you need more details.

Thanks,
Steve